# I Would Appreciate Help for a New Cocoa Programmer

Tags: cocoa, objective-c-2.0

I am making a simple program for my daughter who designed a game.  I simply want the Mac to come up with a random number from 1 to 6, compare it to the user's guess, and then get the difference which is used to determine how many spaces the player can move on her board game.  Everything works, except the difference the program generates is always 3.  It is generating the random number correctly and is reading the user's input correctly.  Here is the code.  I would really appreciate help.  I am new to this and realize there is probably a very very simple answer.  I have searched and searched and have not come up with a solution.  At one point it was generating the difference correctly, but now it's not.  Thanks so much!

```
//
//  AstroGuessAppDelegate.h
//
//  Created by Trent Evans on 3/7/11.
//  Copyright 2011 __MyCompanyName__. All rights reserved.
//

#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

int macPick;
int numberGuess;
int numberDiff;

@interface AstroGuessAppDelegate : NSObject {
    IBOutlet NSWindow *window;
    IBOutlet id moveResultLabel;
    IBOutlet id thinkingLabel;
    IBOutlet NSComboBox *numberGuessBox;
}
- (IBAction)compareNumbersAndSendResults:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)macThinkOfNumber:(id)sender;
@end



//
//  AstroGuessAppDelegate.m
//
//  Created by Trent Evans on 3/7/11.
//  Copyright 2011 __MyCompanyName__. All rights reserved.
//

#import "AstroGuessAppDelegate.h"

@implementation AstroGuessAppDelegate


- (IBAction)macThinkOfNumber:(id)sender {

    macPick = (arc4random() % 6) + 1;
    NSString *thinkingLabelText = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"Ok. I'm thinking of a number."];
    [thinkingLabel setStringValue:thinkingLabelText];

}

- (IBAction)compareNumbersAndSendResults:(id)sender {

    numberGuess = [numberGuessBox intValue];
    numberDiff = macPick - numberGuess;
    if (numberDiff<0) {
        numberDiff = numberDiff * -1;
    }
    NSString *moveResultLabelText;
    if (numberDiff=0) {
        moveResultLabelText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"My number was %i. Your number was %i. The difference is %i. \nBLAST OFF!\nMove forward 6 spaces", macPick, numberGuess, numberDiff];
    }
    if (numberDiff=1) {
        moveResultLabelText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"My number was %i. Your number was %i. The difference is %i. \nORBIT!\nMove forward 4 spaces", macPick, numberGuess, numberDiff];

    }
    if (numberDiff=2) {
        moveResultLabelText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"My number was %i. Your number was %i. The difference is %i. \nRE-ENTRY!\nMove forward 2 spaces", macPick, numberGuess, numberDiff];

    }
    if (numberDiff=3) {
        moveResultLabelText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"My number was %i. Your number was %i. The difference is %i. \nSPLASHDOWN!\nMove forward 1 space", macPick, numberGuess, numberDiff];

    }
    else {
        moveResultLabelText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"My number was %i. Your number was %i. The difference is %i. \nBLACK HOLE!\nSorry. You don't get to move.", macPick, numberGuess, numberDiff];

    }


    [moveResultLabel setStringValue:moveResultLabelText];

}


@end
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `if` statements you have the assignment operator `=` rather than the comparison operator `==`, so every `if` is true and the last one executed is the one for `3`.

You'd be better off using a `switch` for this:

```
switch(numberDiff)
{  case 0:
       moveResultLabelText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"My number was %i. Your number was %i. The difference is %i. \nBLAST OFF!\nMove forward 6 spaces", macPick, numberGuess, numberDiff];
       break;
   case 1:
      etc.
   default:
      moveResultLabelText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"My number was %i. Your number was %i. The difference is %i. \nBLACK HOLE!\nSorry. You don't get to move.", macPick, numberGuess, numberDiff];
}
```

Next you have declared all your variables as file globals at the top:

```
int macPick;
int numberGuess;
int numberDiff;
```

If these are shared between different methods then they should be instance variables, `macPick` is an instance variable in this case. This should be declared in the `@interface`:

```
@interface AstroGuessAppDelegate : NSObject
{
   int macPick;
   etc.
```

It looks like the other two are only used by `compareNumbersAndSendResults` so declared them there:

```
- (IBAction)compareNumbersAndSendResults:(id)sender
{
   int numberGuess;
   int numberDiff;
   etc.
```

On a minor note change:

```
numberDiff = numberDiff * -1;
```

to

```
numberDiff = -numberDiff;
```

or even use the abs function:

```
numberDiff = abs(macPick - numberGuess);
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  I new it was dumb.  I've even read in the books I'm working through about the havoc '=' vs '==' can cause.  I know this was a silly thing and very basic stuff, and I really appreciate you taking the time to help a rookie.  I originally had the abs function but was trying everything in the world to change my code to see if I could fix it.  Ha.  The 'case' thing is very helpful.  Again, something I read, but I'm very early in the game and didn't think of it.

Answer (score 0):

Heh, it took me a minute to figure out what was going on.

Simply put, there is a difference between:

```
if (numberDiff=1) {
```

And

```
if (numberDiff==1) {
```

The first one is doing an *assignment*.  It's going to take the value `1`, assign it into `numberDiff`, and the use the new value of `numberDiff` as the condition for the `if` statement.  Since `1` is a true value, this will succeed.

The second one is doing a *comparison*.  It's going to take the value `1` and compare it to the value of `numberDiff`.  If the two values are equal, then the overall statement will produce a true value.

So basically, you need to use `==` and not `=`.

You're always seeing the results for the "3" case, because that's the last if statement.  The program is able to assign `3` into `numberDiff`, so it's going to update your `NSTextField` with the text from that case.

Comment: Thank so much for taking the time to help a rookie!